# Jframe image + textfield

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame, mixing

Hi i am trying to make a simple frame displaying an image a textfield and a button, but for some reason the textfield is invisible, since i am quite nooby at java and even more at these graphical things can you help :)
THE CODE

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package solverapplet;

 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class AwtImage extends Frame{
  Image img;
  String base="R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==";
  /*public static void main(String[] args){
  AwtImage ai = new AwtImage();
  }*/
  public void setbase(String a){
  this.base=a;

  }
  public void refreshimage(){
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();  
                      byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(this.base);          

                      BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));  
                      //File imgOutFile = new File("newLabel.png");  
                      //ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", imgOutFile);
                      img = bufImg;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AwtImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

  }
  public AwtImage(){
  super("Solve");
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();  
            byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(this.base);          

            BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));  



            MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);


          img=bufImg;
          mt.addImage(img,0);
          JTextField textfield= new JTextField("Text field 2", 8);
          add(textfield,"South");
          setSize(400,400);
          //pack();
          setVisible(true);
          addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
          dispose();
          }
          });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AwtImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }
  public void update(Graphics g){
  paint(g);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
  if(img != null)
  g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, this);
  else
  g.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
  }
}
```

It gets instantiated by an other class.

Comment: Rather than writing `add(textfield, "South");`, I recommend writing `add(textfield, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` This serves two purposes: a) It foolproofs your code, because any typing errors show up at compile-time b) it serves as a kind of implicit documentation, meaning it's easy to understand. I can take one look at the second option and instantly know what LayoutManager you're using and what you're doing with the textfield.

Comment: You're not using a JFrame, you're using an java.awt.Frame, there is a MASSIVE difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you've overridden the paint method without making a call to it's super, meaning that it never gets a chance to paint.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(img != null)
        g.drawImage(img, 100, 100, this);
    else
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
}
```

When using `java.awt.Frame` you will find it difficult to achieve what you.  `java.swingx.JFrame` allows you to override the `paintComponent` method, which allows you to paint the background of the component, but the `java.awt.Frame` does not.

You should also avoid mixing light and heavy weight components (I know, it's apparently fixed), but if you can, just avoid it.